# How to set a Javascript timer to delay prefetch?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, prerender

I am using prefetch/prerender on an HTML page.

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="example.com" />
```

I want to delay this action using JS.

Comment: Does this still prefetch as expected even though the the HTML has already been parsed? If so I guess you could do this on window.onload instead of a timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using setTimeout and document.write. Tested in chrome and it loads the site after 2s (saw in network panel)

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.write("<link rel='prefetch' href='http://www.google.de' />")
    }
    ,2000
);
```

Comment: Do I put this in the head of the document? Do I have to have this on load? Or just within standard script tags?

Comment: i think it doesn't matter, i put it in the dev console, so it was after page load. should be fine in the head in script tag or also in onload method